# Creating POSIX queues from kernel modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to do something a little strange: I'd like to create and manage POSIX queues from a kernel module. I have two processors talking over RPMSG, and would like the details of the IPC to be abstracted from userland applications to improve portability. Both sides have POSIX queue support, so by mapping all POSIX queue semantics over RPMSG in the driver, IPC going across cores would look similar to normal inter-process IPC.

I'm new to Linux kernel dev, but it seems like this isn't something that can be done easily. There doesn't seem to be an internal API for ipc/mqueue.c, and I can't call the mqueue syscalls from within a kernel module. Would my best bet be to expose the RPMSG endpoints directly via sysfs and manage the queues in userland? Or maybe just create a new RPMSG driver that implements the POSIX mqueue spec? Is this just a terrible idea?

Comment: Why haven't you mentioned [`kfifo`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/kfifo.h) which in fact implements a queue?  See documentation [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/kfifo.html)

Comment: Look at `kdbus`, that’s probably what you want.